# Google map api open tab with route from geolocation to placeId

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to create a link that open a new google map tab with route from `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` to a specific `placeId`.

If there is geolocation a problem then, open a new tab without origin completed 
Here is what I try:

```
const options = {
  placeId: 'ChIJDyx4bNhu5kcRqJ3RkAPGMEk',
  latitude: 48.925606,
  longitude: 2.327621,
};

const mapOptions = {
  zoom: 15,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(options.latitude, options.longitude),
};

const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('Map'), mapOptions);
const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

service.getDetails({
    placeId: options.placeId,
  }, (result, status) => {
  if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    alert(status);
    return;
  }
  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: result.geometry.location,
  });
});

$('.js-ItinaryFromI').on('click', () => {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      const pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude,
      };
    }, () => {
      // The problem seems to come from this line : 
      window.open(`https://www.google.com/maps/dir/origin=pos&destination=place_id:${options.placeId}&travelmode=driving`, '_blank');
    });
  } else {
    // And this line
   window.open(`https://www.google.com/maps/dir//place_id${options.placeId}&travelmode=driving`, '_blank');
  }
});
```

Any idea please ?

Comment: Use the [Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)

Answer (score 0):

You should use **[Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start)** if you wanted to calculate directions between location. You can search for directions for several modes of transportation, including transit, driving, walking, or cycling.

These parameters (origin, destination, travel_mode) are used in Google Maps Directions API and probably won't work well using Google Maps.

I also noticed in the code you provided that certain variables were not properly concatenated into the request. Hence, your request would not provide accurate results.

Here's a sample of valid request:

```
window.open('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin='+pos.lat+','+pos.lng+'&destination=place_id:'+options.placeId+'&travelmode=driving&key=YOUR_API_KEY', '_blank');
```

Don't forget to include your **[API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start#get-a-key)** in each request.

I modified your code a bit. You can check it below:

```js
const options = {
      placeId: 'ChIJDyx4bNhu5kcRqJ3RkAPGMEk',
      //placeId: 'ChIJ51Ic7BXIlzMRK2WH8qoM6Ek',
      latitude: 48.925606,
      longitude: 2.327621,
};

function initMap() {
    const mapOptions = {
      zoom: 15,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(options.latitude, options.longitude),
    };

    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('Map'), mapOptions);
    const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.getDetails({
        placeId: options.placeId,
      }, (result, status) => {
      if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        alert(status);
        return;
      }
      const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: result.geometry.location,
      });
    });
  
    if ( navigator.geolocation ) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
          const pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude,
          };
          document.getElementById('js-ItinaryFromI').addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.open('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin='+pos.lat+','+pos.lng+'&destination=place_id:'+options.placeId+'&travelmode=driving&key=[API-KEY]', '_blank');
          });          
        });      
    } else {
      alert('Geolocation not found!');
    }
      
}
```

```css
    html,body,#Map {
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
    }
```

```html
  <button id="js-ItinaryFromI">Click Me</button>
  <div id="Map" ></div>
<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCzjs-bUR6iIl8yGLr60p6-zbdFtRpuXTQ&callback=initMap&libraries=places">
    </script>
```

You can try this using **[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/hesiseg/edit?html,js,output)**. For some reason it doesn't work here in Stackoverflow's code snippet. I don't know why.

Good luck and happy coding!